# MVC and JQuery Mobile : Radiobutton looses state on post

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I am using Jquery Mobile on a page which is set data-ajax="false" to always refresh content on load.

A javascript set's the radiobutton state (checked/not checked) on document.ready(), however it only is successful on the GET request.

When I click the save button and the page loads again after it's POST, then the selection is gone.

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CurrentCulture);

    <input type="radio" name="radio-language" id="radio-language-eng" value="en-US" />
    <label for="radio-language-eng">English</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-language" id="radio-language-esp" value="es-MX" />
    <label for="radio-language-esp">Spanish</label>
    <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" />
}

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var currentCulture = $("#CurrentCulture").val();
    $('input[type=radio][name=radio-language]').checkboxradio();
    $("#radio-language-eng").prop("checked", currentCulture == "en-US");
    $("#radio-language-esp").prop("checked", currentCulture == "es-MX");
    $('input[type=radio][name=radio-language]').checkboxradio("refresh");

    $('input[type=radio][name=radio-language]').change(function () {
      $("#radio-language-eng").prop("checked", this.value == "en-US");
      $("#radio-language-esp").prop("checked", this.value == "es-MX");
      $("#CurrentCulture").val(this.value);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Checking the value of the hiddenfield, it holds the correct culture, so why does the radiobutton looses it's state?

Comment: What do you mean _"radiobutton looses it's state"_? What is the point of all this as opposed to simply binding the radio buttons to property `CurrentCulture` using `@Hml.RadioButtonFor(m => m.CurrentCulture, "en-US")` (ditto for "es-MX")

Comment: I am trying to check the "correct" radiobutton on .ready(), depending on the model value. If it's a better approach to use the html helper, then I'll look into that.

Comment: Remove the hidden input, use 2 x  `@Hml.RadioButtonFor()` as per my last comment and delete the scripts.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! That worked like a charm!! (set the reply and I'll mark it as answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace you code including the script with `RadioButtonFor()` and strongly bind to your model. Note you need to give the buttons an `id` attribute to work with the associated label and to prevent invalid html.

```
@Hml.RadioButtonFor(m => m.CurrentCulture, "en-US", new { id = "eng" })
@Html.Label("eng", "English")
@Hml.RadioButtonFor(m => m.CurrentCulture, "es-MX", new { id = "esp" })
@Html.Label("esp", "Spanish")
```